# Datetime error in iis 7 server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-7

I have screen in c# asp.net webapplication, where i add news on particular dates.And can edit those dates also.It workes in my local sytem.But shows datetime error when it was running in iis 7 server(Used sql database).And i knew that the short date and long date format in server was different from local system.So i changed date format in local system same as in iis.But still it is working properly.

Comment: could you post the relevant code ?

Comment: Please add the error text also here ,I hope it is the "date out Of range" error !

Comment: To be specific.This is the code i used:-string stringDate="19/11/2012";
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(ff_SetDate(stringDate));
        public string ff_SetDate(string datetime)
        {
                string[] date = datetime.Split('/');
                string DD = date[0];
                string MM = date[1];
                string YY = date[2];
                string dt = DD + "/" + MM + "/" + YY;
                return (dt);           
        }

Comment: And error in iis is"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Answer (score 1):

Instead of guessing culture settings write code that sets one you need before reading from database/restore after unsing [Thread.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx) property. Simialr to code below (need to also use CurrentUICulture, chose cuture you need and wrap code around setting/restoring into `try`/`finally` for real code)

```
 var oldCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
 // read from DB
 ...
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCulture;
```

Comment: Am not able to follow this.Could you please explain me a little more.